# Add automatically a team?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm programming a game in which I have to set a team based on the **position** of the player when the game starts. Can you help me?

```
var playerz = [];

room.onPlayerJoin = function () {
  playerz.push({
    name: player.name,
    id: player.id,
    team: 0,
    position: { x: null, y: null },
  });

room.onGameStart = function () {
  TeamRed = playerz.filter(
    (p) => p.position["x"] === 103 && p.position["y"] === -178.5
  );
  TeamYellow = playerz.filter(
    (p) => p.position["x"] === -206 && p.position["y"] === 0
  );
  TeamBlue = playerz.filter(
    (p) => p.position["x"] === 103 && p.position["y"] === 178.5
  );
};
```

What I've done is to rename the player based on the position, but I actually need to rename the **team** based on these positions. Of course, I could do it manually verifying the position of each player but in some maps players are more than 10 so I need to do it **automatically**. Can someone help me?

P.S. Never mind about player, it's a built-in-game parameter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
TeamRed.forEach(plr => playerz.find(o => o.id == plr.id).name = "Red");
```

I think this is what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Nope :( I want to set the team (TeamRed, TeamBlue, TeamYellow) based on the position of the player